# Passing existing array gives different results than passing new array with elements out of that array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm programming a game for Android. The color of game elements is set through ColorTheme objects that store RGBA-values.
On initialization of e.g. a triangle an array with RGBA-values out of an ColorTheme object is being passed to the constructor.
Although the Colors in the ColorTheme-Object never change after initialization, the color of the triangle does. I'm trying to figure out why.
I noticed that it works like I want it if I pass a new Array with elements from the ColorTheme-Array rather than passing the ColorTheme object itself to the Triangle constructor. This really shouldn't matter because there is no such thing as pointers in Java (right?).

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int width, int height) {

//...

mThemes = new ColorTheme[]{
            new ColorTheme(
                    new float[]{0.20f, 0.71f, 0.91f, 1.00f},    // blue circle
                    new float[]{1.00f, 1.00f, 1.00f, 1.00f},    // white obstacle
                    new float[]{1.00f, 1.00f, 1.00f, 1.00f},    // white triangle
                    new float[]{0.00f, 0.60f, 0.80f, 1.00f}     // shadow
            ),
            new ColorTheme(
                    new float[]{0.27f, 0.40f, 0.80f, 1.00f},    // purple circle
                    new float[]{1.00f, 1.00f, 1.00f, 1.00f},    // white obstacle
                    new float[]{1.00f, 1.00f, 1.00f, 1.00f},    // white triangle
                    new float[]{0.60f, 0.20f, 0.80f, 1.00f}     // shadow
            ),
            new ColorTheme(
                    new float[]{0.60f, 0.80f, 0.00f, 1.00f},    // green circle
                    new float[]{1.00f, 1.00f, 1.00f, 1.00f},    // white obstacle
                    new float[]{1.00f, 1.00f, 1.00f, 1.00f},    // white triangle
                    new float[]{0.40f, 0.60f, 0.00f, 1.00f}     // shadow
            )
    };

//...

// Values keep changing after initialization like this    
mShadowTriangle = new Triangle(mScreenRatio, mThemes[outerThemeIndex].theme[3],true);

// They don't like this 
mShadowTriangle = new Triangle(mScreenRatio, new float[]{mThemes[outerThemeIndex].theme[3][0],mThemes[outerThemeIndex].theme[3][1],mThemes[outerThemeIndex].theme[3][2],mThemes[outerThemeIndex].theme[3][3]},true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a pointer *per se*, but there are still object references, and they act like pointers (except that they don't allow for pointer arithmetic). That means that there's all the difference in the world between

```
new Blah(x);
```

and

```
new Blah(copyOfX);
```

Each time, if these are objects we're talking about, they get passed by reference. That means that if the constructor of `Blah` decides to make modifications to the object that gets passed to it, then the first one will end up with `x` being modified, but the second one won't, because only the copy will be modified.

The bottom line is that if you have an array that you don't want messed with, and you're passing it to code that might modify the array it gets given, you want to pass a clone rather than the original.

If you've got an array of primitives (say an `int[]`), you can use

```
int[] copyOfX = Arrays.copyOf(x, x.length);
```

to get a clone. Be aware that if the elements of the array are themselves objects, though, then this will give you a *shallow copy* (and you will then need to look up the difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy).

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays, even arrays of primitives, are `Object`s. As a consequence, if you don't pass a copy (using your method, or one of the [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T[],%20int%29) methods) then changes to the original reference will modify your `Object`'s reference.